# Apacher mod_rewrite - how to have clean URLs with .html?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set in my Apache config to allow mod_rewrite:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ service apache2 restart
```

But why my URLs with **.html** won't work? eg:

```
mysite.com/about.html
mysite.com/contact.html
```

but it works with:

```
mysite.com/about
mysite.com/contact
```

How can I have URLs with **.html** working as well?

**EDIT:**

This is the .htaccess (modx):

```
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see
# http://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0/administration/friendly-url-solutions
# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments
# and especially for the first three commented out rules

#php_flag register_globals Off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=permanent,L] . 

# without www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# without www all domains
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

I don't see any rule there saying about having .html...

Comment: What? are you having some `.htaccess` working or have some rule defined some where, it is vague because you don't need mod_rewrite to show extension at the end of url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing it doesn't make any sense to have these two opposite meaning directives one after another:

```
AllowOverride None
AllowOverride All
```

You just need later part that is:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Secondly to support extension-less URLs you just need to enable `MultiViews` option as:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```